# stringbuffer is faster than string in concatination may i know how they make it happen

Tags: java, string, append

When we work on Concatenation of strings in java

why **StringBuffer** is faster than **String** 
 In every definition it is said that Stringbuffer is faster thaan string but      haven't  got clear details on how it is made possible

Comment: No they are just mentioning stringbuffer is faster thaan string but i am asking how it is made possible?

Comment: You are probably reading an old textbook or blogpost. The difference in speed in recent versions of Java is about the same for simple concatenation, and even where it matters you should probably use `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you concatenate `String` objects, the content of the strings is copied into a new `String` instance. So if you have a string 50 characters long, and you append another character, then those 50 characters all have to be copied into a new string.

`StringBuffer` (or `StringBuilder`) has a `char` array whose length may be greater than the current amount of content it contains. As more text is added to the `StringBuffer`, the array gets filled up until the capacity is reached. The content of the array does not need to be completely copied every time.

(In practice, Java is smart enough to optimise many string concatenations to use `StringBuilder` instead, even if you don't write them explicitly.)

Answer (score 4):

**String** is immutable, if you try to alter their values, another object gets created, whereas **StringBuffer** is mutable so they can change their values. Thats why **StringBuffer** is faster than **String**.

Answer (score 1):

***From java documentation ;***

> To improve performance, instead of using string `concatenation`, use
>   `StringBuffer.append()`
>
> String objects are immutable—they never change after creation. For
>   example, consider the following code:
>
> ```
> String str = "testing";
> str = str + "abc";
> ```
>
> The compiler translates this code as:
>
> ```
> String str = "testing";
> StringBuffer tmp = new StringBuffer(str);
> tmp.append("abc");
> str = tmp.toString();
> ```
>
> Therefore, copying is inherently expensive and overusing it can reduce
>   performance significantly.